# How to get Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (version 2.0) source codes with all dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to exclude all NuGet packages from my project. In other words, I need to build all libraries and only after that add their .dll to project.
I know that all libraries are in GitHub, but downloading each library is not an option. Is there any source that contains whole meta-package sources?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. When you add a reference to a NuGet package, it downloads the DLLs and adds a reference to them. Your application won't compile without those references, so there is no way to "do it later" as you presume.

Comment: I need sources of all DLLs

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should ask the question that you really want to ask, because what you are asking makes no sense at all. The whole point of compiling down to DLLs is so they can be included in other projects without having to compile the source code yourself. What do you need the source code for?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this https://github.com/aspnet/Universe !

AspNetCore/Universe contains Microsoft.AspNetCore.All project in "src" folder and all linked submodules in folder "modules".
To get all sources (include modules sources like Identity,EntityFramework, etc..) you should use:

**git clone --recursive https://github.com/aspnet/Universe.git**

Without **--recursive** flag "modules" folder will be empty.